# How to compare 2 statements in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

Is it possible to compare 2 String like this.

```
String test1 = "foo bar abc";
String test2 = "bar abc foo";
```

Typically is not a String `equals` in java.

I'm thinking to use `ArrayList` or `array` by splitting string by space and compare.

Is there any other methods available? 
which one is better?

I want answer **foo bar abc** and **bar abc foo** are the same. I want to know if the same words appear in both or not.

Comment: what do you want to compare? the words?

Comment: yes and then use a for each loop and check if array2 contains each word from array1

Comment: Split words and sort. Compare arrays are the same

Comment: @cricket_007 I think sorting isn't really needed. but It might be more efficient.

Comment: @cricket_007 He only said that he wants to know if array2 contains each word from array1. He didn't say that it cannot contain more. So checking for equality might not be the right thing... And the List interface has a nice containsAll method by the way ;)

Comment: @ItamarGreen Splitting both and looping over one from the other is O(n^2), I think. Sorting and comparing would be O(n logn). Obviously for such small arrays, doesn't matter much

Comment: @cricket_007 I thought so. I'll implement it into my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your strings represent sets of words (i.e. collections with no duplicates), the natural solution would be to use [Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

```
    String test1 = "foo bar abc";
    String test2 = "bar abc foo";

    HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(test1.split(" ")));
    HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(test2.split(" ")));

    System.out.println(set1.equals(set2));
```

Comment: And what if `test2 = "bar abc abc bar foo foo"`? Should that return true, or false when compared against test 1?

Comment: That question should be directed to the OP. I guess he considers them equal in this case. But I can be wrong here...

Comment: I agree - it's just worth mentioning, though. Technically the same words are there, so if duplicates aren't important, this is fine

Comment: Agree. Added clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can split two strings, sort result arrays and compare them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test1 = "foo bar abc";
    String test2 = "bar abc foo";

    System.out.println(method(test1, test2));
}


private static boolean method(String test1, String test2){
    String[] tokens1 = test1.split(" ");
    String[] tokens2 = test2.split(" ");

    Arrays.sort(tokens1);
    Arrays.sort(tokens2);

    return Arrays.equals(tokens1, tokens2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list out of each string, by splitting both strings into separate words (using regex).
Then you can check if the second list contains all the values that are in the first list:

```
String test1 = "foo bar abc";
String test2 = "bar abc foo";
List<String> list1 =Arrays.asList(test1.split("\\s+"));
List<String> list2 =Arrays.asList(test2.split("\\s+"));
if(!list2.containsAll(list1))
    return false;//or print out "false", whichever suits you
```

Comment: I am not downvoter, but I think because you have given only code without any explanation.

Comment: @cricket_007 edited code... I completely forgot about adding an explanation O.O

Comment: @Simze better now? :P

Answer (score 0):

That's is one of many possibilities:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

(...)

String test1 = "foo bar abc";
String test2 = "bar abc foo";

if (Arrays.asList(test1.split("\\s+")).containsAll(Arrays.asList(test2.split("\\s+")))) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```